# Override a typescript definition file

Tags: typescript

I am using a library called `aurelia-breeze`.  The `aurelia-breeze.d.ts` file that npm sends with the library has an error in it.

The error is small and easily fixed.  But since it is in my `node_modules` folder, it is a huge problem for my auto build pipeline.

**Is there a way for me to tell typescript to ignore a definition file?**

What I have tried:

- Creating a copy of the file in my `src` folder that has the issue fixed.  It had no effect
- I have node_modules in my `tsconfig.js` `exclude` section, but that does not effect `.d.ts` files.
- Directly changing the file.  This works, but creates auto build issues.  Plus `yarn` reverts the changes when I run it.

Comment: Depending of the fix you need to do, we can easily augment the `aurelia-breeze` module. What change do you want to do?

Comment: @Diullei - I need to change this `import breeze from 'breeze-client';` to this `import * as breeze from 'breeze-client';`.  (Here is the issue I reported about it: https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze/issues/47)

Comment: @Diullei - Or I can remove that line completely.  Nothing in the definition file needs it.

Comment: Ok, it's not a case of module augmentation. Sorry.